# How to save several iteration of a variable to Excel

Tags: excel, matlab, for-loop, iteration

I have something simple like the following, where I call the script for 5 iterations.

```
for n=i:5
(call script)
end
```

How can I save one variables output to excel. Say variable A changes for each iteration:

```
A=5

A=2.7

A=6
```

.
.

Can this be saved into Excel in one column?

Should I use:
    xlswrite('output.xlsx',A,.....
With some range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is to do something like this:

```
for i=1:5
    % (call script)
    A(i) = i; % Or to the obtained value
end
xlswrite('my_xls.xls',A);
```

If you want to save more values, then you could do something like this:

```
for i=1:5
    % (call script)
    A(i) = i; % Or to the obtained value
    B(i) = i; % Or to the obtained value
end
M = vertcat(A(:)',B(:)');
xlswrite('my_xls.xls',M);
```

The xls file is created in your Matlab's current directory.
Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the first one and it only output 1 answer into the created excel spreadsheet. Should this be run through the command window or editor?

Comment: @Jake Try the code again. Copy the code on each gray block to see what it does. It should create an excel with the A and B matrixes as rows. The code works fine both in the command window or in the editor.

Comment: it now outputs the rows with 5 values. But the values are the iteration number. I tried to set A(i) = A instead of i as you recommend and it only outputs one value and the rest is the iteration number.

Comment: Try a formula that depends on i. For example x = [5 7 3 9 12]. Then put A(i) = x(i)^2+1. It should put the values of x^2 + 1 in the excel file.

Comment: @jespenstana : the example you give works. But can it be modified to output something which is not dependent on i? I have a value that changes (each time I run the script), which I am looking to output to Excel.

Comment: Yes, the important thing is that M must be a matrix. How you obtain the values inside the matrix is not important. It could be the solution to a system of linear equations Mx = b, or any other calculations you perform.
Check the xlswrite documentation (type doc xlswrite).